# fulltext search, group by and count issue

Tags: php, mysql, search, filter, full-text-search

I've got a text input for search and when you write keyword in this sql query runs:

```
SELECT * FROM test 
where match(title, desc, adress, city, state, country)
against('istanbul')
```

on my search results page i got a search filter side bar and im in trouble with listing states without any duplicates and counting how many rows are found with same name.

to be more clearly what i've got is:

```
Alabama () 
Alabama ()  
Alabama () 
Arizona () 
Minnesota () 
Minnesota ()
```

what Im fighting for

```
Alabama (3) 
Arizona (1) 
Minnesota (2)
```

and php

```
echo '<ul id="filterStates">';
while ($states= mysql_fetch_array($sql)) {
echo '<li><a href="'.$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'].'&state='.$states['state'].'">'.$states['state'].'</a><em>( )</em></li>';
}
echo '</ul>';
```

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT concat('city','(',count(*),')')
FROM test 
where match(title, desc, adress, city, state, country)
against('istanbul')
group by state
```